# Updating a file without saving it to new using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I'm making my python script automatically update my excel file however with `openpyxl` it seems that I can only save my file by making a new one.
Now I could overwrite the file everytime but is it possibe to just append to a file? Or would the best be overwriting the same file.

Code for what i'd want to append/save to the original file:

```
import openpyxl

#File Declarations
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("sales.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

sheet['E11'] = int(3)
workbook.save(filename="sales1.xlsx")
```

Comment: What does "append" mean in that context? There is only one cell `E11` in the whole sheet, you can append another one.

Comment: many file formats have structure which can't append data directly on disk. You have to read all data to memory, add new value, and save all data back on disk. BTW: why don't you save with the same name `workbook.save(filename="sales.xlsx")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the same filename to the workbook.save()

instead of workbook.save(filename="sales1.xlsx") use workbook.save("sales.xlsx") this will save changes in original file

```
workbook.save("sales.xlsx")
```